# Unable to access working Netgear CM1100 cable modem login page

Tags: login, modem

I have a Netgear CM1100 modem with local IP of 192.168.100.1.

1. I have tried Netgear R6230 router with IP of 192.168.1.1. I am able to connect to the modem login.
2. I also tried Netgear R6700 router with IP of 192.168.1.1. I cannot connect to the modem.
3. I also tried Netgear MK62 mesh system IP 192.168.1.1. I am able connect to the modem.
4. I currently have ASUS ZenWifi AX Mini with IP 192.168.50.1. I cannot connect to the modem.

The internet works in all cases. Why all these different options you may ask? A mesh system is better for my house and I like the Netgear except for the fact that my Ring devices will not remain connected. The router uses a single SSID for both 5 and 2.4. The Ring devices are 2.4 only.
The ASUS is able to set separate SSIDs so everything connects and works. So why do I want to access the modem? I am able to see the upstream and downstream power levels. There are times that they vary out of recommended range (usually get too hot). When that happens I can put an attenuator on the cable connection. I know this is a cable company issue but their fix is to do exactly what I do with the attenuator. Problem is, the levels vary.
What I'm looking for is a way to access the modem from the existing mesh without disconnecting it, and setting a static IP on a PC connected directly to the modem. I know a little about this stuff but not enough to know what to do.

Comment: you need to be on the same subnet as the modem. 192.168.100.x  probably just plug into the modem and it will give you dhcp on its subnet.

Comment: I know I can plug in a stand-alone PC with a static address of 192.168.100.2 to the modem, however, to do that I have to disconnect the router. That disconnects my security and smart devices from the internet.  I can access the modem through two different models of router and I cannot from two other router models. That would seem to indicate that some configuration in two routers is allowing the connection. I can't seem to find anything that would explain the difference however. And unfortunately, the router I want to use is one that won't let me access the modem sign in.

Comment: what router is plugged into the modem?